# how object members work in c#

Tags: c#, oop

I am learning c# and I came across a code that was of the following structure. The actual code in my office that used the below code structure had several hundred lines and being new to c#, I found it difficult to understand.
Can some one give me a small example with one or two members and methods in  `'Class ABC'` and '`ClassXYZ`' using the structure that I have mentioned below to help me understand.

The doubts that I have are as follows:

In 'class Test', I understand that 'result' is an object of `XYZ class`. The writeline method prints a text, but what does `result.One.Two.Three` mean and  would One, Two and Three be members of Abc  class.

A small example of above situation would greatly help the cause... Thanks!!

```
public class Abc
{

// Do not know what this contains

}   

public class XYZ
{   
  public Abc buy(string Name)
  {
    // Some Operations     

return response;
  }
}

public class Test
{   
   public static void main()
   {
     XYZ xyz =  new XYZ();
     Abc result = xyz.buy("Don");

     // This prints some actual value say : John
     Console.WriteLine(result.One.Two.Three);
   }

}
```

Comment: `One`,`Two`,`Three` could be properties or fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the 'One' property is a member of Abc. The 'Two' is a member of "One" and the "THree" is a member of "Two".

A property of an object is of a certain type. That type also has properties which are of a type which itself has other properties and so on.

```
public class Two
{
    public string Three {get;set;}
 }

  public class One
  {
       public Two Two {get;set;}
   }

  public class Abc
  {
      public One One {get;set;}
   }

   //result.One.Two.Three
```

Comment: thanks mate.. yep after going through the code with ur answer, it is exactly how it is

Answer (score 0):

In c# members are accessed by . so in the code above
One is an accessible member of class `Abc` ,`Two` is an accessible member of member `One` of some class (which is not clear here),and `Three` is an accessible member of member `Two` of a type which is not clear here.
The structure would be something like this:

```
Class A
{
 B Two;
}
Class B
{
  C Three; //c could be simple type or string or...
}

Class Abc
{
  A One;
}
```